# Stripe credit card fields not working on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

My WordPress website is using Stripe and WooCommerce plugin to accept credit card.

But on final checkout page, the credit card field is not working and showing very small size:

[image]

"Live Publishable Key" and "Live Secret Key" are correct.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have updated your strive plugin?

Comment: You can inspect element the field and see what the css looks like.

Comment: https://github.com/understrap/understrap/issues/682 seems to be a known issue, see if tis helps

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#section-45

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of solutions for this problem, like having SSL installed, using the correct domain, etc.

On my site there was an error with the PayPal Checkout, which I had active too, that caused the stripe credit card form to not get filled with the according input fields. When I deactivated PayPal Checkout I could use the form just as expected again.

So far that's enough of a solution for me since I can continue using the normal PayPal implementation on WooCommerce without needing PayPal Checkout.

The PayPal Checkout error I received was:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FUNDING' of undefined at getFundingMethods".
```

I have not been able to resolve it yet though without deactivating PayPal Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may due to the incorrect domain, license keys from Stripe or the setup process in the documentation haven’t been completed:

Please follow this documentation step by step:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#section-2

Comment: I checked, everything is fine, looks like Stripe blocked the authentication process.